# Select the first row from each group after groupby (Multiindex)

Tags: pandas, group-by, multi-index

I am doing data analysis, and conducted the groupby to get the 'count' and 'sum' by 'year' and 'product' (already sort by count in each year)

The df is like:

|  |  | count | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| year | product |  |  |
| 2015 | product A | 9 | 23 |
|  | product | 5 | 46 |
| 2016 | product A | 7 | 17 |
|  | product B | 7 | 42 |
|  | product C | 3 | 78 |
| 2017 | product B | 9 | 32 |
|  | product C | 8 | 24 |
|  | product A | 1 | 72 |
| 2018 | product A | 3 | 33 |
|  | product B | 1 | 82 |

The 'year' and 'product' are the indexes, and 'count' and 'sum' are the agg columns.

I would like to retrieve the Max count (the first row) from each year.

The result would be like

|  |  | count | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| year | product |  |  |
| 2015 | product A | 9 | 23 |
| 2016 | product A | 7 | 17 |
| 2017 | product B | 9 | 32 |
| 2018 | product A | 3 | 33 |

How can I deal with it?

Thanks

Comment: kindly share your data as code (much easier since your data is a MultiIndex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the first row from the each year, you can do:

```
print(
    df.reset_index(level="product")
    .groupby(level="year")
    .first()
    .set_index(["product"], append=True)
)
```

Prints:

```
                count  sum
year product              
2015 product A      9   23
2016 product A      7   17
2017 product B      9   32
2018 product A      3   33
```